# How to anti-alias the fonts in visual studio in windows forms application?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

[enter link description here](http://i46.tinypic.com/33x79kk.png)does any one know the code to anti alias the fonts so that the project looks more professional.tell me the code and where to insert it in the project.As of now the fonts looks jaggy the programming language is visual C# 4.0 .net and IDE is VS 2010

for example this is a label1 what do I need to insert to anti alias

```
this.label1.AutoSize = true;
this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(189, 187);
this.label1.Name = "label1";
this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(31, 13);
this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
this.label1.Text = "from";
```

[why this fonts look so crisp and smooth whereas the fonts in windows form doesnt look so good](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/11/24/15-beautiful-high-quality-free-fonts/)

Comment: What fonts are you using? What makes you say they are *not* anti-aliased?

Comment: i meant text only and not text in image

Comment: ive uploaded the image link in the description

Comment: It is a system setting.  Your screenshot shows all text already being anti-aliased, using ClearType.  That's the normal setting.  SysInternals' ZoomIt tool is a good utility to show you the pixels.

Comment: http://tutmash.com/wp-content/uploads/tdomf/98/sub-pixel-thumb.jpg

Comment: I want text to look smooth as this one http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/domus-titling-screenshot-directwrite.png

Comment: ClearType is the superior anti-aliasing technique.  If you don't like ClearType then you should turn it off.  Or make the effort to tune it first.  Google "cleartype tuner" and take the first hit.