# Anti aliasing or smoothing fonts of labels ,textbox etc in windows forms

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to anti-alias the fonts in visual studio in windows forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110677/how-to-anti-alias-the-fonts-in-visual-studio-in-windows-forms-application)

how can I make my font look smooth like [the upper font in this image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a8e533c7b6.png)??
I not talking about cleartype(it is enabled) but the text dont look smooth and crisp as they are on websites

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110677/how-to-anti-alias-the-fonts-in-visual-studio-in-windows-forms-application